# Spring cloud gateway cannot find Fluent Java Routes API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying my hands on Spring-cloud-gateway. While going through the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.0.0.M7/multi/multi__configuration.html#_fluent_java_routes_api) I found that we can configure routes not only in yml/ properties file, but also using Fluent Routes API. Here is the snippet from the documentation.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(ThrottleGatewayFilterFactory throttle) {
    return Routes.locator()
            .route("test")
                .predicate(host("**.abc.org").and(path("/image/png")))
                .addResponseHeader("X-TestHeader", "foobar")
                .uri("http://httpbin.org:80")
            .route("test2")
                .predicate(path("/image/webp"))
                .add(addResponseHeader("X-AnotherHeader", "baz"))
                .uri("http://httpbin.org:80")
            .route("test3")
                .order(-1)
                .predicate(host("**.throttle.org").and(path("/get")))
                .add(throttle.apply(tuple().of("capacity", 1,
                     "refillTokens", 1,
                     "refillPeriod", 10,
                     "refillUnit", "SECONDS")))
                .uri("http://httpbin.org:80")
            .build();
}
```

But I am not able to find this class `Routes`. Not sure If I have missed anything. I am using spring boot `2.0.0.M`7 and I have `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` depependecy included.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Routes` is no longer available. Add a `RouteLocatorBuilder` parameter to `customRouteLocator`. I'll fix the docs.

Comment: Fixed here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/commit/baa8b027fa4ec37062e9b7f5dcbd296ca79e6b48

Comment: Thats nice. Cheers.

Comment: It's a sample filter